# jquery raty get score in 0.5 interval

Tags: jquery, raty

I am using jQuery Raty JS, and i want score always in an interval of 0.5, no matter where it clicks on stars
For eg. 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5

Expected result: stars should display in an interval of 0.5

Currently, the code is like

```
$('#custom_p').raty({
  half: true ,
  halfShow    : true,
  precision  : true,
  round      : { down: .25, full: .6, up: .76 },      
  click: function(score, evt) {
  alert('ID: ' + this.id + "\nscore: " + score + "\nevent: " + evt);
}});
```

Maybe have to look in round param

Comment: `precision: false` might do the trick...

Comment: tried with that too, does'nt work

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
click: function(score, evt) {               
    var score = Math.round(score*2)/2;
}
```

But not the best way :/

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.